# ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 268435456

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with Wordpress self-made plugin and self-made theme. Locally it works fine but in the server I get this error in php log:

```
ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 268435456 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker '85.XX.XX.XX', file '/usr/home/www/wp-admin/admin.php', line 109), referer: http://mysite.com/wp-admin/

ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 268435456 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker '85.XX.XX.XX', file '/usr/home/www/wp-admin/admin.php', line 109), referer: http://mysite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin-page
```

I don't know if it's after I get this message or what is the reason, but then my front-end pages keep waiting forever doing nothing, no apache or php log entries. These pages were working before.

I don't have access to Apache conf. and contact with server admins is somehow difficult so I don't really know where the problem is or what to do next, I tried testing step by step commenting everything but even with a simple "echo" the wordpress page template kepps waiting forever with no log entries.

Any clues?

Thank you

Comment: Today my site started with the same problem.. Is your site hosted in MediaTemple?

Comment: No, I think this was 1and1, don't remember...

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin is trying to increase the `memory_limit` setting. This attempt is thwarted by PHP - I'm assuming maybe the [Suhosin patch.](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) The plugin probably does this to avoid problems with too little memory; however, this is usually futile because the limit is enforced by the provider. (I've never seen an actual *error* come out though,  usually the setting is just ignored.)

Try removing the commands trying to increase the limit.

Comment: I didn't program any memory increase, so is Wordpress doing it somewhere? Does it make sense the wainting-forever issue in the font-end after this alert? Thank you

Comment: @user yeah, then WP must be doing it. Check wp-config.php, IIRC there is a memory limit setting in there